# SSL handshake error in java 7

Tags: java, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to connect my domain which is on `SSL` in `java` but it is throwing `exception`

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

However the same code runs perfectly on `java 8`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to add the certificates to java 7 cacerts file

Comment: If that's the case then how it is working on java 8 ?

Comment: Because the cacerts file is found in the JRE directory, so it's different per Java version.

Comment: run your  program with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and look for information about the handshake or add relevant sections of the created log to your question. I have seen handshake failures when a server and client support different ciphers and can not decide which to use during handshake.

Comment: I am using weblogic server and trying to connect to another URL which is HTTPS through HTTP POST, The certificate on server supports only TLSv1.2 protocol so what I did is added command line parameter on weblogic server but it is still showing TLSv1 when connecting to the https URL

-Dweblogic.security.SSL.protocolVersion=TLSv1.2 -Dweblogic.security.SSL.minimumProtocolVersion=TLSv1.2